# Python how to round Timestamp object to the previous full hour

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

Hi have a list of timestamp objects:

```
Timestamp('2021-07-07 10:00:03'), Timestamp('2021-07-07 10:02:13'), Timestamp('2021-03-07 12:40:24')
```

And I want to round each element at the hour level, to get:

```
Timestamp('2021-07-07 10:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-07-07 10:00:00'), Timestamp('2021-03-07 12:00:00')
```

The type of each element is

> Pandas Timestamp (pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp)

.
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: How do you store your timestamps? Is that a tuple, a list, a datetimeindex, something else? You say list but you posted a tuple.

Comment: @timgeb this is a Pandas Series of Timestamps (a column in dataframe)

Comment: Okay then why did you say list? You could have saved both of us a lot of time. Next time please construct a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
>>> df 
                 time
0 2021-07-07 10:00:03
1 2021-07-07 10:02:13
2 2021-03-07 12:40:24
```

Use

```
>>> df['time'] = df['time'].dt.floor('1h')
>>> df 
                 time
0 2021-07-07 10:00:00
1 2021-07-07 10:00:00
2 2021-03-07 12:00:00
```